# How to create a file one directory up?

Tags: python, io

How can I create a file in python one directory up, without using the full path?

I would like a way that worked both for windows and linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `os.pardir` (which is probably always `".."`)

```
import os
fobj = open(os.path.join(os.pardir, "filename"), "w")
```

Comment: by using os.pardir it will take the relevant parent directory syntax for the OS your application is currently running on. So yes, it will work on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: `os.path.join` uses the right kind of directory separators for the OS (`:` for Mac OS 9 etc..). `os.pardir` the correct parent directory name, but does anyone know any OS not using `".."`?

Comment: OpenVMS uses very different directory syntax; but os.pathsep still returns ".." and you can use Unix-style paths within python with no problem.

Answer (score 20):

People don't seem to realize this, but Python is happy to accept forward slash even on Windows.  This works fine on all platforms:

```
fobj = open("../filename", "w")
```

Comment: Is this an official feature?  I don't remember seeing it in the documentation, and os.path.join always made me think that programmers should not rely on '/' being the path separator…

Answer (score 2):

Depends whether you are working in a unix or windows environment.

On windows:

```
..\foo.txt
```

On unix like OS:

```
../foo.txt
```

you need to make sure the os sets the current path correctly when your application launches.
Take the appropriate path and simply create a file there.

Comment: Python will understand forward slash on Windows, too.